# How to GetData of attribute value in child

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, configurable-product-options

I am trying to get attribute value "barcode" for child product in magento2.

Below code working for cofigurable parent product.

```
$_product = $this->getProduct();
$_barcattr = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('barcode');
$_barcode = $_barcattr->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
echo $_barcode;
```

But i'm trying to get barcode for child product. Below code shows error.

```
$_children = $_product->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProducts($_product);
foreach ($_children as $child){ 
$_childbar = $child->getResource()->getAttribute('barcode');
$childatt = $_childbar->getFrontend()->getValue($child);
}

Please le me know how to get barcode value..
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mark the attribute "barcode" as "Used in product listing": "Yes" and you should be able to get it as you are already trying.
When retrieving the simple products from a configurable product, only the attributes marked as "used in product listing" are loaded

Comment: Thank you @Marius